# Why Driver.SwitchTo not always works in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use the code

```
windowHandles = SeleniumHelper.WindowHandles(); 

// click...

if (SeleniumHelper.WindowHandles().Count > windowHandles.Count)
{
    windowHandles = SeleniumHelper.WindowHandles();    
    while (pageTitle == SeleniumHelper.Driver.Title)
    {   
       SeleniumHelper.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandles[windowHandles.Count - 1]);
       Thread.Sleep(2000);                                                                         
    } 

    // do something...  

    SeleniumHelper.Driver.Close();
    SeleniumHelper.BackToMainWindow();
}
```

The problem is that the driver finds the window, but does not switch to it.
Maybe there is a different way to switch to another window, like switch by javascript?

Comment: `driver.switchTo().window()` is working fine. Share exactly what you did if you need help with it.

Comment: while running on a table, I switch to another window, doing some stuff and goes back to the window contains the table. and so over and over again. However, sometimes the selenium does not switch between the windows, although I see it is finding the windows

Comment: By share exactly what you did I meant the code that doesn't work for you, i.e. the switch to the window.

Comment: windowHandles = SeleniumHelper.WindowHandles(); 

click...   

if (SeleniumHelper.WindowHandles().Count > windowHandles.Count)
{
    windowHandles = SeleniumHelper.WindowHandles();    
    while (pageTitle == SeleniumHelper.Driver.Title)
    {   
       SeleniumHelper.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandles[windowHandles.Count - 1]);
       Thread.Sleep(2000);                                                                         
    } 

    do something...  

    SeleniumHelper.Driver.Close();
    SeleniumHelper.BackToMainWindow();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in

```
SeleniumHelper.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandles[windowHandles.Count - 1]);
```

You always switch to the last window regardless the `while` loop condition. Try this

```
string currentWindoe = SeleniumHelper.Driver.CurrentWindowHandle();
while (pageTitle != SeleniumHelper.Driver.Title)
{   
    SeleniumHelper.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(SeleniumHelper.Driver.CurrentWindowHandle());
    Thread.Sleep(2000);                                                                         
}
```

Or

```
string currentWindow = SeleniumHelper.Driver.CurrentWindowHandle();
foreach (string window in SeleniumHelper.Driver.WindowHandles())
{
    if (!window.equals(currentWindow))
    {
        SeleniumHelper.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(window));
    }
}
```